# equivalent of Excel Goal Seek function in Python or MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, excel, function, math

How would I implement a [Excel Goal Seek](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-Goal-Seek-to-find-a-result-by-adjusting-an-input-value-ef3495fe-9ddc-4249-89b4-0e24406b7fcb) function with Python or mysql?

This is the scenario :

in the agency where i work they buy items and then sell to an online store, this online store apply 3 different FEES , calculated on the final price.
The agency wants to earn a fixed amount of money on the final price, so i need to calculate the final price with the fees and the amount they want to earn.

I know the amount money they want to earn and the initial price, and the fees in % , i don't know at what price i need to sell the items for earn that specific amount of money.

With excel they use the goal seek function that calculate the final price with all the fees and the fixed amount the agency want to earn, i would like to do it with python or mysql.

EX :

```
a1 = 270.0$ # This is the price they buy the item
c2 = 3.50$ # This is the shipping Price
c3 = 0.10 # This is the FEE of the store in percentage (10%)
c4 = 0.03 # This is the FEE for the credit card (0.3%)
c5 = 0.35$ # This is the Fixed FEE for the store 0.35$
d1 = 5$ # This is the amount they want to earn when they sell the item
x = ? # This is the final price they need to sell the item for earn d1
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does the Excel Goal Seek function do in excel?

Comment: Please add the scenario that you want to solve

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm , note that you can reformulate "goal seeking" `f(x)=y` as root-finding `0=g(x)=f(x)-y`.

Comment: i added the scenario and the example, thanks for your help

Comment: With Excel they also have to give a formula involving the parameters. There is no built-in "do my unspecified algebra for me" function in any system

Comment: @ilmetu almost there. Do you have a forumla of how the fees and store charges are taken? e.g. earnt_amount = (x - a1 - c2 - c5) * (1 - c3 - c4)

Comment: @ptimson the store charges the fee on the final price (x) that's why i going crazy to find the formula . c3 and c4 are calculated on the final price and the final price is + c5

Comment: @ilmetu does c3 & c4 apply to a1 & c2? And is c2 a cost?

Comment: @ptimson i think the correct equation is this :

Comment: @ptimson i think the correct equation is this : x / 1.22 - c5 - a1- (x*c3)-(x*c4) i think i loose the point and get mad... i will look at the code you write and adapt to our needs . i will let you know later ... thanks so much !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python you could do the following. Note the formumla may need adjusting

```
a1 = 270.00  # This is the price they buy the item in $

c2 = 3.50  # This is the shipping Price in $
c3 = 0.10  # This is the FEE of the store in percentage (10%)
c4 = 0.03  # This is the FEE for the credit card (0.3%)
c5 = 0.35  # This is the Fixed FEE for the store $0.35

d1 = 5.00  # This is the amount they want to earn when they sell the item in $
x = 0.00  # This is the final price they need to sell the item for earn d1

while True:
    # Assumed Formula - this may need to be adjusted to match your criteria
    earnt_amount = ((x - a1 - c2) * (1 - c3 - c4)) - c5
    x += 0.01
    if earnt_amount >= d1:
        break

print ('Price "x" should be: {0}'.format(x))
```

Comment: @ilmetu if you update your question with the formula I can add it to the answer

Comment: You also should invest in a better method than tabulating with a fine grid. Imagine the solution would be about x=10000. The secant method is the most simple efficient method.

Comment: is there a existing python package that we can take advantage of? for example, if we could pass in our function as the input parameter of the package to get the optimal output.